# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url') NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to create a component which displays the featured image coming from the GraphQL API.

But I get the following error.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

```
import React from "react";

const PostDetail = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg lg:p-8 pb-12 mb-8">
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden shadow-md mb-6">
        <img
          src={post.featuredImage.url}
          allt={post.title}
          className="object-top h-full w-full"
        />
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostDetail;
```

I have already tried adding the question mark, as I have seen in other Stack Overflow threads.

```
import React from "react";

const PostDetail = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg lg:p-8 pb-12 mb-8">
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden shadow-md mb-6">
        <img
          src={post?.featuredImage?.url}
          allt={post?.title}
          className="object-top h-full w-full"
        />
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostDetail;
```

The error disappears, but the image is still not displayed.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^6.0.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.16",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^13.3.2-canary.14",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.3",
    "sass": "^1.62.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your `post` has `featuredImage` field? Have you tried to log `post` object and check how it looks like?

Comment: {
  post: {
    title: 'React Testing',
    excerpt: '"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."\n' +
      '"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."',
    featuredImage: { url: 'https://media.graphassets.com/K5YrOn9bScapizWNOEka' },
    author: { name: 'Boss', bio: 'Hello', photo: [Object] },
    createdAt: '2023-04-26T21:54:37.960701+00:00',
    slug: 'react-testing',
    content: { raw: [Object] },
    categories: [ [Object] ]
  }
}

Comment: in which component did you print console.log the prop. in `Postdetail` or in the parent of `PostDetaul`

Comment: So your `post` has another `post` field inside? Or where did you put the log?

Comment: Can you include your code showing the component that contains `<PostDetail .../>`?

Comment: `post.featuredImage` is undefined. You have not provided enough code to show why. But it is, and you should look into that, and trust the error is correct.

Comment: Updated, it works. I forgot to add ({post})